# How do you loop through a file to an array and create new objects in the loop?

Tags: java

I created a  new public class in eclipse named Soda that Contains the following private data fields: name (String), price (double), quantity (integer), and ounces (integer).

Has setters (accessors) and getters (mutators) for each of the data fields. The setters for price, quantity,
and ounces leave the associated data field unchanged if a negative value is sent to them.

A public method named reduce that subtracts an amount (parameter) from the quantity data field only
if the quantity is greater than or equal to the amount and the amount is positive. The method does not
return a value.

In my main class named `popMachine` i am supposed to read sodas from a file into a pop machine (an array of soda objects), reduce the quantity of sodas in the
machine, and then write the soda information back to another file. In this part i am supposed to  Open the file for reading and read each Soda into the array
 Stop reading when there are no more lines to process or the
 array is filled with sodas.

In each loop iteration, I will need to add a new Soda
 object to the array, get the 4 lines of data associated with
 that soda, and set the soda object with that data.

```
    public static int fillMachine(Soda[] popMachine,
 String fileName) throws IOException
 {
   Soda soda1 = new Soda();
   fileName = "Sodas.txt";
   File file = new File(fileName);
   if(!file.exists()) {
     System.out.print("File Open Error: " + file.getName());
     System.exit(1);
   }
//my problem is here in the loop I don"t know where to continue or how to loop through the rest of the file
   Scanner input = new Scanner (new File (fileName));
   while (input.hasNextLine()){
     for(int i = 0; i < fileName.length(); i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < fileName.length(); j++) {
         popMachine[i] = soda1.setName(j) +
                         soda1.setPrice(j + 1) +
                         soda1.setQuantity(j + 2) +
                         soda1.setOunces(j + 3);
       }
     }

   }
 }
```

Comment: _"I created a  new public class in eclipse named Soda that Contains the following private data fields: ... "_ -- NO, don't describe the class, show us the class declaration in Java.

Comment: what is that `popMachine[i] = soda1.setName(j) + soda1.setPrice(j + 1)` `soda1.setQuantity(j + 2) + soda1.setOunces(j + 3)`

Answer (score 0):

sTo get a line of data from a file as a string, you can use Scanner's nextLine function. You can then do whatever you want with this String.

Now without knowing the exact layout of this text file you speak of, here's how I can help you.

Say you have a text file and its contents look like this:

```
Hello
2
0.14
Hi
4
0.92
```

What you know is that every 1/3 line is a string, every 2/3 line is an int, and every 3rd line is a double.
So you'd do something like this to create a new soda object in the array and set its variables based on the lines. You might have to do a few tweaks for your needs but I think this can help:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new File (fileName));

    for(int j = 0; scanner.hasNextLine(); j++) {
        popMachine[j] = new Soda();
        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if(i == 1) {
                popMachine[j].setName(line);
            } else if(i == 2) {
                popMachine[j].setOunces(Integer.parseInt(line));
            } else if(i == 3) {
                popMachine[j].setPrice(Double.parseDouble(line));
            }
        }
    }
```

(Don't forget to close your scanner with scanner.close();)

Obviously this isn't a perfect answer and is not completely error proof, but this is the best I can give you with limited material and a kind of confusing question.

EDIT: You can simplify my snippet further by integrating the two for statements like so:

```
        for(int i = 1; scanner.hasNextLine();) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if(i % 3 == 1) { // These make sure it's every 1/3, 2/3, 3/3 line etc. Plugging in 1 % 3 will give one, 4 % 3 is one, etc.
                popMachine[j].setName(line);
                i++;
            } else if(i % 3 == 2) { // 2 % 3 is 2, 5 % 3 is 2.
                popMachine[j].setOunces(Integer.parseInt(line));
                i++;
            } else if(i % 3 == 0) { // You get the gist
                popMachine[j].setPrice(Double.parseDouble(line));
                i++;
                j++;
                popMachine[j] = new Soda();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Im sorry if I didnt specify before each element in the array contains the 4 lines of data associated with the soda so element 1 would have the name, price, quantity, and ounces of the first soda and element 2 would have the next and so on